# How do I determine the path or action for my Lambda when setting up AWS API Gateway through the CLI?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I have a lambda function (Java) deployed in AWS Lambda.

I have set up an API Gateway resource and method through the UI console at API Gateway.

I am trying to set up the API Gateway through the command line, with something like

```
aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id <rest-api-id> \
  --resource-id <resource-id> \
  --http-method GET \
  --type AWS \
  --integration-http-method POST \
  --uri <lambda-arn> \
  --request-templates file://mapping.json
```

Note, `<lambda-arn>` is the ARN of the Lambda.

I get an error of the form

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutIntegration operation: 
AWS ARN for integration must contain path or action
```

What is the *path* or *action* I need to provide?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the path should be of the form

```
arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/<lambda-arn>/invocations
```

But why this should be the case is an absolute mystery to me.

The documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html) clearly states

> The uri parameter is the ARN of the function-invoking action.

And whose birthday is it on 31 March 2015?

Comment: `uri` is the ARN for the [Invoke API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) action for your Lambda function. 2015-03-31 is the Lambda API version's date of birth ;)

Comment: AWS guys should find other places to show humor...